# HTML5 sessionStorage strange behavior

Tags: html, local-storage, session-storage

I am using sessionStorage to save a few values for my app, but it seems that when the devices goes into stand-by/turns off screen the sessionStorage is lost, one of the things that I have stored is a sessionID to make sure people are logged in, when the app returns the user is logged out, because there is no sessionStorage data.

When is sessionStorage reset/expired?

Answer (score 0):

It's browser dependent, but generally at the end of a 'browsing session' however the particular browser defines that.  If you want to persist data between sessions, use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Thanks Robert, i was actually using localStorage, and a coworker changed it to sessionStorage, just to avoid cleaning up at log out.